# convert Mono<Order> to Order object

Tags: reactive-programming, drools

I am trying to explore the reactive programming using drools. I am doing POC to apply the drools rules on the object.

```
public Mono<Order> findByOrderNo(String orderNo) {
          Mono<Order> order = orderDAO.findByOrderNo ( orderNo );
          KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("rulesSessionpart2");
          kieSession.insert(order); // rules are not getting applied as it requires the object type 
                                       //as input
          kieSession.fireAllRules();
          kieSession.dispose();
          return order;
     }
```

This is my test rule:

```
import com.reactive.practice.springreactor.model.Order 

rule "ReturnEligible for Order" 
when 
  orderObject: Order(itemReturnEligible==true) 
then 
  orderObject.setDescription("bdfgdfdfhdf"); 
end
```

Here the method kieSession.insert(order) requires an object as input, but in the above code, I am passing Publisher type of Mono.

I tried converting Mono to Order object using block(). As in many documentation suggests it is not recommendable to use as it is blocking the operation.

**Is there any other way to convert the Mono to Order Object.**

Any help is appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: Change your rule to not require an Object type. You need to show an example of your rule. At the end of the day, if you're trying to do a rule against the contained object, you're going to have to give the rule a way to access that object. If you're going to do a rule against the Mono, then the rule is going to have to be written to work against mono.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, Thank you for the explanation. I am new to the drools concept. Basically I don't have an idea how to change the rule to make work on MONO object. import com.reactive.practice.springreactor.model.Order
rule "ReturnEligible for Order"
 when
  orderObject: Order(itemReturnEligible==true)
 then
     orderObject.setDescription("bdfgdfdfhdf");
 end                                                    => this is my rule,any idea how to change this rule to work on MONO?

Comment: The left hand side of your rule (the "when" clause) needs to be using the Mono, not the Order. If you write the rule against the Order, you need to get the order out of the mono which means that you need to do a blocking action (which is bad in reactive programming.) Start by figuring out how you'd do this in an "if" statement in Java, and then convert that into the "when" clause in your rule.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thanks for your inputs. It is really helpful for me at least how to start. I will try and let you know If I get blocked.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas do you have any sample where it shows applying the drools rule on Mono or Flux objects?. I am searching but I am not finding any sources related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers

1) Use a dedicated testing library like reactor-test

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing

```
  StepVerifier.create( 
    appendBoomError(source)) 
    .expectNext("thing1") 
    .expectNext("thing2")
    .expectErrorMessage("boom") 
    .verify();
```

2) Calling block in a test isn't a problem.

If you unit test method is blocking and must complete before you return then block is arguably the right call to make. But there are still better ways to do this like StepVerifier above.

In reactive style programming, calling block in your production code is almost always a bug unless you are specifically the framework code in a blocking context (e.g. a synchronous servlet API that runs the process).  Generally you return a Mono and transform other inputs without having a blocking call.

Comment: Thanks for the input. since the Order Object, I am trying to get from Mono<Order> is going to be used for drools where drools methods require an object to insert. As Suggested by Roddy of the Frozen Peas above need to change the rule to specify the Mono<Order> any inputs from you on this?

Comment: I don't know drools, sorry.

Comment: no worries. Thanks for that doc reference. it is helpful.